# is it possible to write sql query in kendo view?

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller, binding, kendo-ui

I have a table keeps the four ID's of four different table. I want to display the names related to each different ID in a grid. I mean:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<grid.Models.TurLink>()
  .Name("grid")

  .Columns(columns =>
  {

      columns.Bound(isim => isim.ID).Width(200);


      columns.Command(komutlar =>
          {
              komutlar.Edit();
              komutlar.Destroy();
          }
      ).Title("Değiştir").Width(200);

  })
```

lists the ID of each different ID. the turlink class is:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    public int? TourID { get; set; }
    public int? StatisticsID { get; set; }
    public int? VehicleID { get; set; }
```

I want to do something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<grid.Models.TurLink>()
  .Name("grid")

  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(**select Fullname from user where ID = (isim => isim.ID)**).Width(200);
```

how can I do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible/allowed/desirable to use SQL statements in the grid. The way to go is to create a ViewModel which contains all the required properties you want to show in the grid.

Comment: the problem is, how to bind the viewmodel to grid?

Comment: You can bind a ViewModel the same way to a grid as an Entity, it's just a class.